# How can I make an Android Gallery redraw when a View changes?

Tags: android, gallery, onconfigurationchanged

I am modifying an `Activity` to implement `onConfigurationChanged(...)` and it contains a extended `Gallery` whose members are sized manually using their `LayoutParams` from the `Gallery`'s adapter.

Unfortunately the `Gallery` initially displays wrong: the extended `View` fills the whole screen. As soon as another item is selected, though, the `View` displays with the correct size.

As an experiment, I tried freezing the dimensions of the selected `View` from the `Gallery#onConfigurationChanged(...)` method and the same behaviour occurred, suggesting the `View` has been updated, but the `Gallery` isn't showing the change.

I also tried calling both `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate()` on the `Gallery` from `Activity#onConfigurationChanged(...)`. Nothing.

How can I force the `Gallery` to redraw with the correct dimensions for the `View`?

Comment: Have you tried notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter?

Comment: refresh your gallery adapter.

Comment: @SnowyTracks that didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure how you are adding your views onto your gallery, however, try calling invalidate() on the views inside the adapter rather than just on the gallery itself.

Comment: Already tried that (from inside the View method that resets everything); still no joy.  `postInvalidate()` didn't do anything either.

Comment: Actually `notifyDataSetChanged()` does work IF I do it from a delayed Runnable.  So clearly the problem is that the `LayoutParams` are not being updated soon enough.

Comment: I called it conditionally (first time after configuration change only) from `Gallery#onDraw()`.  Worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your gallery adapter should do the job.

If it does not, it may be something wrong with your codes somewhere.